# How add and retrieve smart table data for Google cloud firestore

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, ng2-smart-table

I'm engaging with an angular project. I'm using visual studio code as the text editor. I used the `ng2-smart-table` as a table of my project as the `manufacture` component. But I cannot understand how add data as well as retrieve data from firebase. anybody can help me. 
As above mentioned. i use the table template inside the `manufacture` component.

This is my table.
[image]

**manufacture.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'ngx-manufacture',
styles:[],
template: `
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="data"></ng2-smart-table>
`
})
export class ManufactureComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
}

settings = {
    add: {
        addButtonContent: '<i class="nb-plus"></i>',
        createButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
        cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
    },
    edit: {
        editButtonContent: '<i class="nb-edit"></i>',
        saveButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
        cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
    },
    delete: {
        deleteButtonContent: '<i class="nb-trash"></i>',
        confirmDelete: true,
    },
    columns: {
        id: {
            title: 'ID'
        },
        name: {
            title: 'Full Name'
        },
        username: {
            title: 'User Name'
        },
        email: {
            title: 'Email'
        }
    }
};

    data = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Leanne Graham",
            username: "Bret",
            email: "Sincere@april.biz"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "Ervin Howell",
            username: "Antonette",
            email: "Shanna@melissa.tv"
        },

        {
            id: 11,
            name: "Nicholas DuBuque",
            username: "Nicholas.Stanton",
            email: "Rey.Padberg@rosamond.biz"
        }
    ];
}
```

Then what should i do for this problem.

Comment: Check this : https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-firestore-tutorial/

Comment: I already tried for this. but not useful for this case.

Comment: Is your question about how to update the ng2-smart-table when the data source changes? Or is it about retrieving data from Firebase? (These are 2 different problems).

Answer (score 4):

## Behold: the `DataSource`

`ng2-smart-table` uses `DataSource` class to be fully operational in CRUD action.
It is quite easy if you dealing with local DataSource (since it was *stored offline*): They provide `LocalDataSource` class in which derived from their `DataSource`. Your code will look like this.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LocalDataSource } from 'ng2-smart-table';

@Component({
selector: 'ngx-manufacture',
styles:[],
template: `
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="data"></ng2-smart-table>
`
})
export class ManufactureComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
}

settings = {
    add: {
        addButtonContent: '<i class="nb-plus"></i>',
        createButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
        cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
    },
    edit: {
        editButtonContent: '<i class="nb-edit"></i>',
        saveButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
        cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
    },
    delete: {
        deleteButtonContent: '<i class="nb-trash"></i>',
        confirmDelete: true,
    },
    columns: {
        id: {
            title: 'ID'
        },
        name: {
            title: 'Full Name'
        },
        username: {
            title: 'User Name'
        },
        email: {
            title: 'Email'
        }
    }
};

    data: LocalDataSource = new LocalDataSource();

    constructor() {
        this.data.load([
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Leanne Graham",
                username: "Bret",
                email: "Sincere@april.biz"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Ervin Howell",
                username: "Antonette",
                email: "Shanna@melissa.tv"
            },
            {
                id: 11,
                name: "Nicholas DuBuque",
                username: "Nicholas.Stanton",
                email: "Rey.Padberg@rosamond.biz"
            }
        ]);
    }
}
```

I suggest you start from [this](https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/tree/master/src/app/pages/tables/smart-table) to learn how you use `LocalDataSource`.

## So what about the online data source?

Now here's come the real deal.

Last time, I was tasked to create an admin display using Angular, API backend server, and `ng2-smart-table`. I've managed it with `LocalDataSource`, but then come the problem: *This wasn't a local data source*. After some furious night I found [this](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/tree/master/projects/ng2-smart-table/src/lib/lib/data-source), in which shows that they *were* two version on how they handling data: `local` and `server`.

This might hurt you a bit, but I found that you *had* to *Create your own DataSource*. An easy approach is by deriving from [`LocalDataSource`](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/blob/master/projects/ng2-smart-table/src/lib/lib/data-source/local/local.data-source.ts). Your new `DataSource` might look like this.

```
import { LocalDataSource } from 'ng2-smart-table';

export class CustomDataSource extends LocalDataSource {
    constructor() { super(); }

    doSomeDataFetchFromFirestoreAsync(): Promise<any[]> {
        // Insert your data fetch flow here ...
    }

    doSomeAddFunctionToFirestoreAsync(element: any): Promise<any> {
        // Insert your data addition flow here ...
    }

    doSomeDeleteFunctionToFirestoreAsync(): Promise<any> {
        // Insert your data removal flow here ...
    }

    doSomeUpdateFunctionToFirestoreAsync(): Promise<any> {
        // Insert your data update flow here ...
    }

    load(): Promise<any> {
        // Do Some fetch from firestore as aync method, then (on completion) redirect back to LocalDataSource::load() method to maintain the chain
        return doSomeDataFetchFromFirestoreAsync().then((preparedDataSet: any[]) => super.load(preparedDataSet));
    }

    add(element: any): Promise<any> {
        // Do Some add function to firestore as aync method, then (on completion) redirect back to LocalDataSource::add() method to maintain the chain
        return doSomeAddFunctionToFirestoreAsync(element).then((addedElement) => super.add(addedElement));
    }

    remove(element: any): Promise<any> {
       // Same as load or add actually
       return doSomeDeleteFunctionToFirestoreAsync(element).then(() => super.remove(element));
    }

    update(element: any, values: any): Promise<any> {
        // This one is a little bit tricky: The DataSource will try find unchanged `element` first, then updates the value inside unchanged one with `values`
        return doSomeUpdateFunctionToFirestoreAsync(element, values).then((editedElement) => super.update(element, editedElement));
    }
}
```

And now, your code might look like this.

```
// ...
    data: CustomDataSource = new CustomDataSource();

    constructor() {
        this.data.load();
    }
// ...
}
```

## Notes

This approach is *the simple way* I found based on `ng2-smart-table` [`DataSource`](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/blob/master/projects/ng2-smart-table/src/lib/lib/data-source/data-source.ts) definition. If you want to use `ServerDataSource` instead, you can check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/hikaru150s/64de5fbb6c11079bedab8cc248615308) for a partial implementation of `ServerDataSource`.